# Failed to build and install cardano-wallet on ubuntu

Tags: wallet

I'm trying to build and install cardano-wallet on ubuntu according to https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-wallet/#building-and-installing-the-node

But once I run the below command,
`stack build --test --no-run-tests`

I'm getting this error.

```
Received ExitFailure 128 when running
Raw command: /usr/bin/git reset --hard f827a4321e42f528e25f6079f7af3eb18f10d391
Run from: /tmp/with-repo8046/cloned
Standard error:

fatal: Could not parse object 'f827a4321e42f528e25f6079f7af3eb18f10d391'.
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is your ubuntu version?

Comment: Try maybe `git fetch` and then try one more time that command?

Comment: Seems something is broken. :) I will try to reach out developers. Seems cardano-ledger repository don't have necessary commit.

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same error here, at object f827a4321e42f528e25f6079f7af3eb18f10d391 (using Ubuntu 20.04.2)

Comment: i'm using Ubuntu-20.04 with WSL2 on Windows 10.

Comment: I retried today and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This commit was referencing a pull request branch of cardano-ledger that was closed: `jc/benchmark/1-29-0-with-time`. A new branch was pushed to resolve this called `cardano-wallet/deps-for-node-1.30.1`

This is a weird oddity with GitHub where it will refuse to give you an archive for a commit, even if it's aware of it if it's been orphaned and no longer exists in an open branch.